# Nginx won't accept my location configuration

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have a single web site configured in nginx with the configuration shown below. When I visit http://mydomain.com/ the index.html file of my default location is displayed.

However when I visit http://mydomain.com/micro-site/ the default nginx 404 page is displayed. Why is the micro-site location configuration being ignored?

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /micro-site/ {
        root /var/www/microsite/;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/webroot/;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Inspection of error log is showing that:

If I leave the root / location in, then it is looking inside /var/www/webroot/microsite for the microsite location.

If I remove the / location, then it is looking in /etc/nginx/html/

I am not sure where /etc/nginx/html/ is coming from.

Comment: Anything useful in nginx's error log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use `alias` directive instead of `root` for the `micro-site` location

Also, seems you use some [PitFalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) (mainly multiple identical `index` directives).

So finally your setup will look like this :

```
server {
   listen 80;
   index index.html index.htm;

   location /micro-site/ {
      alias /var/www/microsite/;
   }

   location / {
      root /var/www/webroot/;
   }
}
```

PS : Take care about the extra `/` in `location /micro-site/` and check if it is really what you need. Maybe you will want to remove this extra `/`